# some support to this Problems compiling to android side in codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

Some one can help me with this issue

please check this issue https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3686

Comment: Discussing it in four different channels doesn't promote faster resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the solution

adding this build hint

codename1.arg.gradleDependencies=\nimplementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.0"\nimplementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"\n

thank you by the support.